# Free Software or Scripts for Formatting SQL Queries

Tags: sql, code-formatting

I'm looking for a script or application that tidies up and reformats SQL queries. I've found some good online SQL formatters (see [here](http://www.wangz.net/gsqlparser/sqlpp/sqlformat.htm)) , as well as some downloadable commercial applications. I'm cautious about using an online service as I don't want to  risk copies of these queries being stored somewhere they might be compromised, if only in a web server's cache (and it is against my employer's policy).

Does anyone know of any open-source applications, scripts, or downloadable freeware that might help me out with this?

It probably bears mentioning that I'm working on a Windows platform at work, but I am open to suggestions for other operating systems.

Cheers!

**Update**

I have used SQLInform as suggested by Vinko Vrsalovic to excellent effect. Thanks Vinko!

Something that might also be worth watching is [SQLTidy](http://code.google.com/p/sqltidy/), a young project on Google Code which could turn into something great in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to try out (SQLinForm is free until 2009). It's weird how some niches totally lack good open source tools.

http://www.trialpay.com/checkout/?c=bb7014d&tid=6rGUpGo

http://www.sqlinform.com

http://www.fileheap.com/software-universal-sql-editor-download-11096.html

An Emacs macro:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/tsql-indent.el

Answer (score 1):

Something else... this freeware tool works for PL/SQL, so maybe there's a use for that in there.

<strike>PL/SQL Tidy</strike> (Broken Link)

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate SQL Refactor (trial) + a Virtual Machine